# How to solve SIGSEGV error for very large array inputs?

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

So, I was solving a problem in HackerEarth which tests your code to very large testcases.  Thus, when I tried to submit the code ,  it passed for first 6 testcases, for 5 others , it gave "Time Limit Exceeded" and for all others, SIGSEGV Signal .

Here's the code:

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
#include<cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);
cin.tie(NULL);
long long unsigned int tc,b, a , d,c;
cin>>tc;
for(int i=0;i<tc;++i)
{
    cin>>a;
    cin>>d;
    cin>>c;
    cin>>b;
    long long unsigned int arr[b+1];
    arr[0]=a;
    arr[1]=d;
    arr[2]=c;



    if(b>=3){

        for(long long unsigned i=3;i<=b;++i)
        {
            // arr[i]%=1000000007;
            (arr[i])=(arr[i-1]+3*arr[i-3]+2*i)%1000000007;
            arr[i]%=1000000007;
        }
        printf("%llu \n",arr[b]%1000000007);



    }
    else{
        printf("%llu \n",arr[b]%1000000007);
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Please help. Thank you.

Comment: That doesn't compile for me. Not only is `arr[b]` a VLA, but `b` isn't even initialized. So even if it does compile, it's undefined behavior, which means that anything can happen, including the SIGSEGV error. The first step would be to rewrite that bit to not exhibit undefined behavior. I'd also get rid of the VLA but it seems like your compiler doesn't mind, so that's up to you.

Comment: When you compile, you should enable all warnings and you should read carefully what the compilers says, example: https://godbolt.org/z/i9tD1p

Comment: And SIGSEGV is not an error, but a signal sent by the kernel of the os that signifies that your program has tried to access a region of the computer memory it has no right to access.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access memory that is not accessible to you. That's the reason for SIGSEGV. You need to declare the array size statically and not dynamically.

However, it is better to use vector, since you are using C++.